# scroll Down and scroll up at the same time in chat app in next js

Tags: infinite-scroll, react-infinite-scroll-component

I am creating a chat app and I want to load messages in both scroll up and scroll down mode, does anyone know a suitable package that has scroll up and scroll down at the same time?

i tried react-infinite-scroll-component ,it was so perfect but the problem is ,it just load more data by scrolling down or scrolling up